# Angularjs - ng-model-options with debounce and required and some conditions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a form where I have a field "First Name",

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="vm.adminuser.first_name" required aria-invalid="true" ng-change="vm.saveEachField()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}">
```

This field is required, I want `saveEachField()` to be called after 500ms of typing and only if it is filled (not when it is empty) and also if there is variable that is set to true. `{{vm.addPage == true}}`

Is this possible, the other way to add these conditions in `saveEachField()` will be long way for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" ng-model="vm.adminuser.first_name" required aria-invalid="true" ng-change="vm.adminuser.first_name && vm.saveEachField()" ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}
```

This should work. As ngchange will be called only if it's valid. Now valid depends upon what validation you've added to field. Else handling it inside that change function is best way.

Update:

userForm.first_name.$valid  would definitely be better, but why not add this one condition in function you are calling on ng-change. If you're calling that function on change of more than one fields then you can create directive like below & add that to every input field which needs to have that saveEachField() on change & remove ng-change in template.

```
.directive('checkEachField', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newValue,oldValue) {
                //console.log('value changed, new value is: ' + newValue);
                if(newValue){
                    scope.saveEachField();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

So it'll lessen your long ngModel variables written inside every ng-change & same ng-change function.

P.S. This solution only if you're having one ng-change function for 2 or more fields. for only one field handling that scope varible value inside function should be pretty simple.

Comment: or we can use ng-change="userForm.last_name.$valid && vm.saveEachField()" to cover all other validations.